# replacing 'eval' with a better solution

Tags: ruby, eval, computational-geometry

This method works, but it works very slowly. I think one of the problems might be the 'eval' statements in the `add_by` method.

Some explanation: every **Node** object has three relevant attributes, `:x`, `:y` and `:neighbors`. `:x` and `:y` are integers representing planar coordinates, `:neighbors` is an array, and nodes are stored in the `@nodes` array. The goal is to find, for each node `k` in `@nodes`, the nodes that are within some distance `d` of `k` and add them to the `@neighbors` array of `k`.

```
 def set_neighbors d
    def add_by dim, d
      dict = {}
      @nodes.each{|k| dict[k] = []}
      @nodes.each_index do |k|
        up = k+1
        down = k-1
        while up < @nodes.length and ((eval '@nodes[k].'+ dim) - (eval '@nodes[up].'+dim)).abs <= d
          dict[@nodes[k]].push(@nodes[up])
          up += 1
        end
        while down >= 0 and ((eval '@nodes[k].'+ dim) - (eval '@nodes[down].'+dim)).abs <= d
          dict[@nodes[k]].push(@nodes[down])
          down -= 1
        end
      end
      return dict
    end
    @nodes.sort_by{|k| k.x}
    exis = add_by('x', d)
    whys = add_by('y', d)
    @nodes.each do |k|
      neighbors = exis[k]&whys[k]
      k.neighbors = neighbors.select{|j| planar_distance(j,k) <= d}
    end
  end
```

My question is, how would you do this without either repeating the `add_by` routine for `x` and `y` or using eval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid eval by using `@nodes[k].send dim.to_sym`.

I'm not sure what your code is doing exactly, but maybe a few pointers:

```
def set_neighbors d
  @nodes.each do |node|
    node.neighbors = @nodes.select do |n| 
      (node.x - n.x).abs <= d && 
      (node.x - n.x).abs <= d &&
      planar_distance(n,node) <= d
    end - node
  end
end
```

Comment: I should mention, though, that the reason not to use .select here is because the number of nodes is very, very large, and the number that are within planar distance is small. So counting up from the index after sorting makes sense... there should be a sort by y in there as well.

Comment: The code you provided does not in fact sort. `sort_by` does not do an in place sort but rather returns a sorted array.

Comment: This is true, but the code as implemented is: `nods = @nodes.sort_by{|k| k.send(dim)}`

Answer (score 2):

How would *I* do it? I'd use the [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) graph database via the neo4j gem ([source](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j)). If you're concerned about performance, this is optimized for graph distance calculations. Also the API is very nice.

That being said, you really don't need eval at all. You can call a calculated method name on an object by using `send`. So you can replace the above with `@nodes[k].send(dim)`, `@nodes[up].send(dim)`, etc.